WebDriver.Print Timeout
I have the following extremely simple example:
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.com");
PrintDocument printDocument = driver.Print(new PrintOptions());
File.WriteAllBytes(printDocument.AsByteArray, "file.pdf");

This works completely for literally example.com. However, in my actual code, I am loading an extremely large webpage with a ton of images. When I print it via my real browser, it takes several minutes to process but ultimately is successful. With WebDriver, it times out with the following error:
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: 'timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000'

The WebDriver.Print() function does not have an overload which accepts any kind of timeout or WebDriver Wait object, so I'm not sure how to allow this to provide a much longer timeout. Can anyone provide advice?
Edit: Just to cover all bases, the PrintOptions object also does not have a timeout: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/print/PrintOptions.html
Edit: Adding additional information on my WebDriver options:
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new();
chromeOptions.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Normal;
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--headless=new");

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
// The following do not seem to change the print timeout
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);


can you include your webdriver options?

@browsermator done, please see my edit

does this machine have a virtual display? (or a real display?)  You might try setting a window size... driver.manage.setsize(dimension)

The machine has a real display but I am running this headlessly. On a small page, it runs fine, so I'm not sure if that's the issue - and unfortunately there is no driver.Manage().setsize() method.
I tried chromeOptions.AddArgument("--window-size=1920,1080");, but it continued to time out.

should be something like: driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1024, 768);  https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/

I have tried driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1920, 1080); both with and without the argument above, no change in the timeout

Try/catch all method calls... GoToUrl() and Print() call.  Where is it thrown?  You might also remove the part that sets the implicitwait timeout.  There is also a wire protocol session timeout which I think is pretty long... (5 mins?) , but as far as I know you can't modify the session timeout.

The Print() call is what throws the exception that I have in the question body

I think it's a pretty new part of the W3C wire protocol, so you might try some of the older methods like "kiosk print" mode, or by using CDP.

part of might what might be slowing this down is your -disable-gpu flag.  Unless you need that (I think it's only needed for certain Linux machines with no display) try removing it.

@browsermator removing --disable-gpu didn't fix it. If you're able to provide an answer for kiosk/CDP, I'm happy to try it and accept it if it works!

never used either method before but CDP should be something like: ((ChromeDriver)driver).ExecuteCdpCommand("Page.printToPDF", { "printBackground": True })   And setting kiosk mode is setting "--kiosk-print" for ChromeOptions, and then just execute script of window.print();
